# Multi store URL's of wrong store with GEOIP extension

Tags: magento2, php-7, geoip

I am using Magent0 2.0.6
PHP 7.0.32

I have multiple store views:
 - Dutch
 - English
 - French

And have GeoIP extension installed that check user's IP and redirect to matching store.

But on the frontend catalog page, if I am in the Frech store, the URL's are still of the Dutch store. But If I check the admin panel I have correct url keys stored depending upon each store view.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: may i known which GeoIP extenstion your using.?

Comment: Sorry, the issue was regarding the migration script used for importing products from magento1 to magento2. I am closing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the issue was regarding the migration script used for importing products from magento1 to magento2. I am closing this issue.